# Why do app icons on force touch popups not appear consistently in the same left or right spot

Tags: icons, user-expectation, ios, labels

On the iOS home screen, if I force touch on the second icon the popup icon stays on the left side of label. If I force touch on the fourth icon the popup icon stays on the right side of label.

Why does Apple move the icon from the left side of label to right side?

What's the benefit of moving the icon?

[image: after force touch the icon show difference side]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It keeps the icons in a single column when the eye scans down from the app icon.

[image]

A user familiar with the icons can easily scan down to find the right selection. They are not *forced* to scan to the far right (in the case of the second example) to find their selection.